# English ivy - Leaves and branches drying and very minuscule insects of white color

Tags: insects, dryness, english-ivy

I recently bought english ivy from one of the flower/plant shop in the healthy state. It has been almost a month since then, it was not doing bad however recently noticed that leaves are drying and falling down.

This plan is kept in hall and has some indirect sun-light, not direct though. Since, the drying was increasing, I checked the plants for the disease or any other issue. Found out that it is attached by some very small minuscule insects of white color. I saw them moving within their web/net. Kind of spider web is formed by these insects.

I am thinking of spraying some soap water to get rid off this. Appreciate any expert advice on this.

Below is image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably spider mites - they're often red, but can be tan coloured or white, and they do create fine webbing.  They thrive in dry air, so ensure you keep the plant sufficiently well watered  ongoing.

Insecticidal soap spray or neem oil spray are suitable treatments, but ensure you cover the entire plant, including backs of leaves, when spraying. You may need to retreat once or twice after the initial treatment. Further information  here https://getbusygardening.com/control-spider-mites/

Comment: Couldn't save this plant even after spraying using neem oil and putting into indirect sunlight.